# Envío de URL con API Whatsapp

Tags: html, jquery, whatsapp

¿Es normal que al enviar una url con la api de Whatsapp usando html y al ser que el receptor del mensaje no me tenga agredado como contacto, la url no se vea como un link sino más bien como un texto?
por ejemplo

[image: Imagen 1]

¿Es normal que aparezca así o hay manera de configurar para que aparezca como link, aunque no estén agregados mutuamente tanto el emisor como el receptor?

[image: Código]

Comment: Puedes poner como lo estas enviando? (El codigo)

Comment: Para evitarte generar el enlace de la api, puedes usar herramientas online para hacer ese trabajo, esta es una de ellas: `https://vilmanunez.com/crear-enlace-whatsapp/`

Comment: @JuanRivera ahi comparti el codigo

Comment: @JhonMaldonado ya lo use y sigue mostrando la url como texto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso pasa por seguridad, la aplicación de WhatsApp bloquea todo enlace externos cuando una persona envía mensaje a otro y este no lo tiene registrado. Esto no lo puedes controlar ya que es parte de la aplicación de WhatsApp.

Comment: Gracias por esa informacion.

Answer (score 0):

En la api de Whatsapp tienes que hacer uso de plantillas, que la misma plataforma te da opciones, en Whatsapp normal la otra persona tiene que tenerte agregado, son políticas de Whatsapp no hay de otra

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, la respuesta que das es muy similar a la que ya dio el usuario @tecnobyte, por favor revisa [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y también te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) así también podrás ganar tu primera medalla. ;)

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).